# Preprocessing tokens and white spaces

Tags: c

If I have the following macro:

```
#define A 10 * 2
```

does that macro replacing list have 5 preprocessing tokens or only 3?

According to the C11 standard it seems as white space is a separation token

> The categories of preprocessing tokens are: header names, identiﬁers,
>   preprocessing numbers, character constants, string literals,
>   punctuators, and single non-white-space characters that do not
>   lexically match the other preprocessing token categories.

Comment: In some examples a space would /could be separation tokens. In your example, there is not. #define A would equal to 20 no matter how many spaces you used.

Comment: _white space is a separation token_, no.  It is a separator _of_ tokens though.  You have 4 tokens, (A, 10, *, 2) resolved into a macro symbol and value

Comment: @ryyker, oh, sorry I wanted to know about the number of tokens only into the replacement list. I edited the question.

Comment: @EvanCarslake: That's not true. Try checking the value of `100 / A`; it won't be 5.

Comment: This ***[link](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/PRE01-C.+Use+parentheses+within+macros+around+parameter+names)*** discusses macros, tokens, replace lists...

Comment: @rici, just checked, you're right. The processing plugs A as 10*2, not as 20 (100/10*2 == 20).

Comment: in general, where writing macros, all parameters need to be surrounded by parens '(' and ')'.  Your code illustrates the reason for using the parens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has three tokens: two preprocessing numbers with an `*` in between. Whitespace is not a token.

The line you quoted includes the wording: `single non-white-space characters`; that is specifically not whitespace.

The standard goes on to say that tokens "can be separated by white space" and that "White space may appear within a preprocessing token
only as part of a header name or between the quotation characters in a character constant
or string literal", all of which pretty clearly state that whitespace is not a token.